# Python add a column with values to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list up tuples in python that looks like this:

[('1', 'Server'), ('2', 'Computer')]

and i want to add a column with the invoicenr, so it looks like this:
[('44', '1', 'Server'), ('44', '2', 'Computer')]

Comment: Create a new list from this. As tuple are not mutable. Or you can overwrite the content of the list using indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
data=[('1', 'Server'), ('2', 'Computer')]

res=[('44',) + x for x in data]
```

output of `res`:

```
[('44', '1', 'Server'), ('44', '2', 'Computer')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension:

```
old = [('1', 'Server'), ('2', 'Computer')]

invoicenr = ['44', '44']

new = [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(invoicenr, old)]
```

output:

```
[('44', '1', 'Server'), ('44', '2', 'Computer')]
```

Comment: Or even less verbose: `[(a, *b) for a, b in ...]`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, I wasnt sure how to use the iterable unpacking `*` so I put it as a, b, c. But yes that is better :) Ive edited my answer

Comment: Your original is very valid, too, as it is more explicit which will make it more readable, especially when naming the variables semantically. The unpacking works more generally, though, in terms of tuple length.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I may have been beaten to the post but here's one method.

```
x1 = [('1', 'Server'), ('2', 'Computer')]
x2 = ('44',)

[x2 + x for x in x1]
```

make `x2` a tuple by adding the column, then use list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Tuples by definition are immutable, so adding to the original tuple directly is not possible. To achieve the result you described however you will have to go through the following:

1- Loop through the original list, you will get a result that will be a tuple.

2- Convert the tuple into a list

3- Add the field (by append, or any other method you would like)

4- Convert the list to a tuple

5- Re-add the new tuples into a new object.

The code might look something like this:

```
newBigList = []
For singleTuple in myListTuple:
    newList = list(singleTuple)
    newList.append("someValue")
    newTuple = tuple(newList)
    newBigList.append(newTuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list with the invoice number prepended:

```
new_list = [(invoicenr,) + item for item in old_list]
```

Note the comma; it's needed to mark that part of the expression as a tuple rather than just parentheses for order of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to create a new list of tuples:

```
A = [('1', 'Server'), ('2', 'Computer')]
B = ['44','44']
C= [tuple([b] + list(a)) for b,a in zip(B, A)]
print(C)
```

[('44', '1', 'Server'), ('44', '2', 'Computer')]